# I want to create one scroll bar for the content with some height and remaining space i have to allocate it for second DIV element

Tags: java, html, css

first div contain the menu items with sub-menus inside it.
second div is for box to display some content.

```
<div id="top-item">
</div>
<div id="bottom-item" class="sub_menu"> 
</div>

.sub_menu
{
position: relative;
width: 204px; 
bottom: 0px;   
}
```

Comment: I would award this a negative bounty if I could.

Comment: Can you please specify exactly what are you trying to achieve. What box do you need space for?

Comment: it contain some content ..If i fixed the position of the second Div , then in my desktop it is working fine..If some other user opens the same webpage, more space is coming below the content.